# Disable selector handler on html output in angular

Tags: angular

It's the second time I face this very same situation...

```
<div id="thisDivHasBeenCreatedBySomeNpmLibrary">
   <div id="otherDiv">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

thisDivHasBeenCreatedBySomeNpmLibrary ---> This will apply text transformation to uppercase on the 1st child.

Ok...it works so far...but let's says that I'd like to encapsulate my "otherDiv" in a component. So, the result rendered will be:

```
<div id="thisDivHasBeenCreatedBySomeNpmLibrary">
   <my-component>
       <div id="otherDiv">Hello World</div>
   </my-component>
</div>
```

Now, this can't work anymore...because the library is actually trying to apply the uppercase upon the selector "my-component".

It could be very awesome to turn off the rendering of the selector itself and get a result like...

```
<div id="thisDivHasBeenCreatedBySomeNpmLibrary">

       <div id="otherDiv">Hello World</div>

</div>
```

Is such thing possible ?

Comment: Do you want to "transclude" your element inside a third party element? Sounds like you need to create your css on your element such that it overrides the third party css. Maybe I don't understand the question.

Comment: @alt255 u r probably right !

Comment: @MarcoJr i was looking at ng zorro and saw they were using the technique that I mentioned in my answer. hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use id selector in `my-component` if you want `my-component`'s div to be  immediate child of `thisDivHasBeenCreatedBySomeNpmLibrary`.

```
<div id="thisDivHasBeenCreatedBySomeNpmLibrary">
   <my-component>
       <div id="otherDiv">Hello World</div>
   </my-component>
</div>
```

example

```
@Component({
  selector: '#thisDivHasBeenCreatedBySomeNpmLibrary',
})
```

see this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nzb1nw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for complete example.

Answer (score -1):

Back in the day this was supported in AngularJS via `replace: true`, but it was depreciated and has not returned.

You can, instead, use an attribute as a selector. Maybe this will work for you?

```
@Component({
    selector: '[foo]',
    template: require('./foo.html')
})
export class FooComponent {
}
```

Then use it:

`<div foo></div>`

Comment: Will not work because <div foo> will still be the 1st child after "thisDivHasBeenCreatedBySomeNpmLibrary" - The target should be the other div.

Comment: btw I wasn't the person that's downvoted you. Thanks for your attempt anyway

Comment: I thought `thisDivHasBeenCreatedBySomeNpmLibrary` was targetting the first child?

So you would have
```
<div id="thisDivHasBeenCreatedBySomeNpmLibrary">

       <div id="otherDiv" foo></div>

</div>
```

`thisDivHasBeenCreatedBySomeNpmLibrary` would target `foo` would it not?

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not entirely clear since you made it so generic, but I would basically say that it may be that the library has configuration options that will allow you to tweak it's output as you require, but if you don't want the results provided by an imported library, don't import it, but implement it yourself.

If the library has an open source license, you can use it's code to get started and customize it to your needs, as long as you follow the terms of the license.

Comment: So is my answer. You want to know how to disable the built-in behaviors of some generic third party library. The answer is simple; don't use it; implement it yourself.

Comment: bla bla bla bla bla